# Rsyslog failed to start CentOS 6.6 Final

Tags: centos6, rsyslog, service

I'm getting the following error message when trying to run: `service rsyslog restart`

```
# service rsyslog restart

: command not foundlog: line 2:

: command not foundlog: line 3:

: command not foundlog: line 5:

: command not foundlog: line 6:

: command not foundlog: line 9:

Shutting down system logger:                               [  OK  ]

Starting system logger: usage: rsyslogd [-c<version>] [-46AdnqQvwx] [-l<hostlist>] [-s<domainlist>]
[-f<conffile>] [-i<pidfile>] [-N<level>] [-M<module load    path>]
                [-u<number>]

To run rsyslogd in native mode, use "rsyslogd -c5 <other options>"

For further information see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I have tried `rsyslogd -c5` as suggested in the error, same problem.

I have tried updating the rsyslog version in yum and I have the latest. SELinux is permissive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like either your configuration file /etc/sysconfig/rsyslog or the init script /etc/init.d/rsyslog is damaged.

Run "rpm -V rsyslog" to check for modified files in the rsyslog package, check the content of the files which that command reports as changed, and check the content of /etc/sysconfig/rsyslog (not checked by rpm -V).